What is trade cardholder?
Around 4:50 in https://youtu.be/aV0qPD11aGQ,
he said he was a trade cardholder of UAW, and worked in a steel mill, making a product that is electric steel for transformers.
What is trade cardholder? What are his job and organization about?

The card shows he is a member in good standing of the United Auto Workers trade union.   Google "Labor unions in the US" for starters.  Labor unions represent their membership in negotiations with large corporations concerning wages, medical benefits, retirement pensions, work hours, workplace safety concerns, and other issues of importance to the workers.

That video is of particular importance today because of the US Presidential Election (November 5, 2024).  Labor Union members traditionally vote Democrat. Most candidates (Democrat or Republican) prefer to be endorsed by Labor Unions. As TimR stated Unions negotiate many different types of wants and needs concerning all members. Members are normally required to pay dues in order to be members.

A trade card is a business card.  The person held such a card (which can be called a membership card) for United Auto Workers (UAW), 'an American labor union that represents workers in the United States (including Puerto Rico) and southern Ontario, Canada'.
This union membership
is  a separate thing from his workplace, a steel mill making steel.  There was no information about his exact role in his company.
